# Is there any way to get gulp to show what changes are currently being processed? Similar to compass watch?

Tags: sass, gulp, compass-sass

I have been using Gulp all summer for my projects, but one very useful feature I miss from compiling SCSS with Compass was that it would show what files have changed immediately as it would start compiling. I find this extremely useful.

Comment: you are most likely looking for gulp watch and you have to listen to the event 'change'

Comment: nice, thanks for the response. Would that go in my gulpfile? Or when I execute the gulp command?

Comment: It will be in your gulp file. https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch#chokidar-instance